# How to combine two multiple trading strategies into single strategy?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

I have Two indicators with me -

1st Indicator - Stochastic with 1 hour time frame
2nd Indicator - MACD with 1 min time frame

I want combine Buy/Sell signals from these two indicators into one single strategy which is as follows:

1. If Stochastic 1 Hour gives buy signal then consider our trading bias or direction as Buy.
   Now As Stochastic runs on 1 hour time frame so it will give less signals.
   As our MACD runs on 1 min time frame so it will give multiple signals for Buy/Sell.
   Now from Stochastic we got our direction which is buy so i would only like to take Buy Trades using
   MACD on 1 min time Frame. Ex - 1 H timeframe given us Buy Signal which is our bias. Now using MACD we
   get Around 30 Buy/Sell Signals. But as bias is already set so we will take only Buy Signal for MACD so
   which reduces the no of signal so it will be less than 30.
2. This will be as same as 1st condition but in opposite direction our bias will be Sell and we will take
   sell trade on 1 min time frame using MACD.

Stochastic Strategy:-

```
strategy("Stochastic Slow Strategy", overlay=true)
length = input(14, minval=1)
OverBought = input(80)
OverSold = input(20)
smoothK = 3
smoothD = 3
k = sma(stoch(close, high, low, length), smoothK)
d = sma(k, smoothD)
co = crossover(k,d)
cu = crossunder(k,d)
if (not na(k) and not na(d))
if (co and k < OverSold)
    strategy.entry("StochLE", strategy.long, comment="StochLE")
if (cu and k > OverBought)
    strategy.entry("StochSE", strategy.short, comment="StochSE")
```

MACD Strategy:-

```
strategy("MACD Strategy", overlay=true)
fastLength = input(12)
slowlength = input(26)
MACDLength = input(9)
MACD = ema(close, fastLength) - ema(close, slowlength)
aMACD = ema(MACD, MACDLength)
delta = MACD - aMACD
if (crossover(delta, 0))
    strategy.entry("MacdLE", strategy.long, comment="MacdLE")
if (crossunder(delta, 0))
    strategy.entry("MacdSE", strategy.short, comment="MacdSE")
```

So I want to combine these two strategies into one.

My Try which does not seems to be right:-

```
strategy("Stochastic MACD", overlay = true,initial_capital = 1000000,currency=currency.USD,default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity,default_qty_value=100)
length = input(14, minval=1)
OverBought = input(80)
OverSold = input(20)
smoothK = 3
smoothD = 3
k = sma(stoch(close, high, low, length), smoothK)
d = sma(k, smoothD)
co = crossover(k,d)
cu = crossunder(k,d)

fastLength = input(12)
slowlength = input(26) 
MACDLength = input(9)
MACD = ema(close, fastLength) - ema(close, slowlength)
aMACD = ema(MACD, MACDLength)
delta = MACD - aMACD

if (not na(k) and not na(d))

    if (co and k < OverSold)
        if (crossover(delta, 0))
            strategy.entry("MacdLE", strategy.long, comment="MacdLE")
        if (crossunder(delta, 0))
            strategy.entry("MacdSE", strategy.short, comment="MacdSE")
if (cu and k > OverBought)
        if (crossover(delta, 0))
             strategy.entry("MacdLE", strategy.long, comment="MacdLE")
        if (crossunder(delta, 0))
             strategy.entry("MacdSE", strategy.short, comment="MacdSE")
```